# google analytics segmenting content

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to segment my pages by url. So for example I created a segment that say that my pages must begins with:

```
/viewtopic.php?f=4
```

It seems ok as it only show a percent of my whole traffic in the stat graph. What I don't understand is why it shows all my traffic in the table below the graph? Shouldn't it only shows the "segmented" pages? Do I have to filter it again using "search" on top of the table? I'm only showing this segment and not the default to see all the traffic.

edit: in fact it doesn't show my whole traffic in the table, but still, it's showing other pages than the one who begins with my pattern. I don't understand how it's filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem -- my current working theory is that it has to do with the fact that these advanced segments are based on visits, not page views.  So the list of pages you are seeing below is a list of pages viewed by people who, on that same visit, saw a page that matches your segment criteria.  Which isn't super-helpful if what you really want is a list of ONLY the pages in that segment.